# Far call pushing wrong IP to the stack

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, nasm, x86-16, callstack

When I run the following code in real mode using VirtualBox, I expect the `call 0x9000:foo` instruction to push the CS and IP registers to the stack. However, when I look the callstack (in VirtualBox's debugger) right after the far call, the return address is set to `9000:000006c6` (instead of `9000:0000078c`), apparently an arbitrary address.

If I use a near call, the return address in the callstack is set correctly.

I'm assembling with NASM and running the code in x86 real mode on VirtualBox.

I know I don't need a far call in this example, but I need it in another part of my code.

```
9000:00000787    call 0x9000:foo
9000:........    ...
9000:00003bac    push bp  ; foo:
9000:........    ...
9000:00003bf0    retf
```

My questions are:

Is it ok to use a far call to call a function in the current segment?

Is there a known reason for the wrong return address in the callstack?

Comment: Yes you can use far call in the same segment of course. Verify your values since the value pushed is the return address so it can never be `767`. it should be `76c`

Comment: Are you sure you're examining the stack correctly, and that you had the right CS:IP value before the `call`?  It should push the CS:IP of the instruction *after* the call, not `00000767`, so maybe `9000:0000076c` if I'm remembering correctly that `call ptr16:16` is 5 bytes long.  The `6c` is suspiciously close to the `c6` you claim to have seen.  And remember that it's little-endian with the offset at the low address, segment at the higher address.  This doesn't look like a [mcve], because what you describe doesn't match what's possible.

Comment: I'm using the VirtualBox debugger. I set a breakpoint at 9000:00003bac and print the stack when the execution gets to the breakpoint.

Comment: I fixed the addresses. Instead of `9000:00000767`, the far call instruction is actually at `9000:00000787`and the return address is `9000:0000078c`.

Comment: The command is `bp 9000:00003bac 0 ~0 k`. I don't think it's executing the `push bp`, because the return address is correct for a near call.

Comment: `78c` **is** the correct return address so if you are seeing that all is well.

Comment: The virtualbox debugger is not very friendly. Reading the answers, I believe I'm doing something wrong. I'll try to get more information tomorrow.

Comment: I see `9000:000006c6` as the return address when I use a far call and `9000:0000078c` when I use a near call.

Comment: You can't be seeing `9000:` in a near call since that doesn't even put the segment on the stack. Also a near call is just 3 bytes so if that's at `787` then you should be seeing `78a` on the stack.

Comment: Ok, I messed the addresses, again. But I'm sure the near call shows the correct address. And the virtualbox debugger shows the segment value for near and far calls.

Comment: I recommend not using `kg` or `k` to walk the call stack unless you have stepped to a point where you have done both `push bp` `mov bp, sp` . VB's call stack dumper walks the stack assuming far calls and that BP is the current stack frame. If you stop right after entering a function you should consider a command like `dw ss:sp` that will start raw dumping data from the current stack pointer location. If doing a near call the first word printed should be the offset to return to, with a far call the offset will be first followed by the segment to return to

Comment: Michael, you are right. The problem was the break point installed before te `push bp` `mov bp, sp`.  I'm getting the correct values now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not using `kg` or `k` to walk the call stack in VirtualBox's debugger unless you have stepped to a point just after the function prologue that sets up the function's stackframe:

```
push bp 
mov bp, sp
```

In some code this is done using an equivalent [`ENTER`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ENTER.html) instruction.

VirtualBox's call stack dumper walks the stack which requires that BP is set up as the current stack frame. If you stop right after entering a function you should consider a command like `dw ss:sp` that will raw dump data from the current stack pointer location as 16-bit words. If doing a near call the first word printed should be the offset to return to, with a far call the offset will be first followed by the segment to return to

---

Note: My experience is that the call stack is traversed assuming a FAR CALL has been done to reach the function, a NEAR CALL may not produce a proper callstack trace.